# Linq filter issue involving a varchar(1) field

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, unicode

I have a field in my database that is varchar(1). I'm not permitted to change it. The only values for this field are 0 or 1.

Here is the where clause of the linq query:

```
where
g.id_Group == idGroup &&
a.AccountOpen.Value == '1'
```

My linq query generated the following sql where clause

```
WHERE ([t1].[id_Group] = 1234) AND (UNICODE([t0].[AccountOpen]) = '1')
```

'AccountOpen' is the varchar(1) field.

I changed the where clause to this manually

```
WHERE ([t1].[id_Group] = 1234) AND ([t0].[AccountOpen] = '1')
```

The second query returns data rows and the first one does not. How can I get this to work WITHOUT changing the database schema?

Comment: varchar(1)?  Did the person who developed this database know what a varchar is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VS2008 L2S designer incorrectly maps varchar(1) and nvarchar(1) to System.Char. (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqtosql/thread/ac91e587-6e91-454c-9fa2-bab20b7a258c)

You can change the mapping for your [n]varchar(1) columns the L2S designer so it is mapped to a string instead. That way you can do normal string comparisons, and also will not get exceptions when materializing records containing empty [n]varchar(1)s.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a char(1) where the char was either 'c', 'h' or 'p' when it did the query it had the same unicode problem, changed the mapping in L2S to a string and all is good. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a `string` instead of a `char` for comparison?

```
where 
g.id_Group == idGroup && 
a.AccountOpen.Value == "1"
```

Comment: The docs hint that CHAR is mapped to string whereas NCHAR is mapped to char.  I'd try this.

Comment: It is mapped to char. Comparing to string throws compile time error

Comment: Do you still get a compile time error if you add a '.ToString()' to 'a.AccountOpen.Value'?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the [UNICODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059(SQL.90).aspx)() function:

> Returns the integer value, as defined
>   by the Unicode standard, for the first
>   character of the input expression

So if the AccountOpen field contains the value "1", the UNICODE() value for that is 49...so it doesn't satisfy the search condition (49 <> '1')